# Retrieving number of likes to a particular facebook page in android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

I want to create a simple "about us" page in my android app from where user can go to the facebook page to have more information about application. I have done this through hyperlink but I am unable to fetch the number of likes for that facebook page using hyperlink.
I have searched the solution for it but everywhere I got suggestion to install "Facebook SDK" which is very tedious & lengthy procedure when I just want to have number of likes on the page. I **don't** want to integrate facebook in my app to provide user facilities like FB login or status update through app etc. My only & simple requirement is to fetch number of likes on the page so is there any simple way to do this or I will have to go with installing Facebook SDK. Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a simple HTTP GET request to the following URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://www.stackoverflow.com%27
```

Change `http://www.stackoverflow.com` to whatever page you want to check.

The above URL will return something like this:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "url": "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
         "normalized_url": "http://www.stackoverflow.com/",
         "share_count": 5206,
         "like_count": 1745,
         "comment_count": 1938,
         "total_count": 8889,
         "commentsbox_count": 3,
         "comments_fbid": 450042939888,
         "click_count": 91
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much..!! This solution worked perfectly fine for me but now its giving me "JsonException: No value for data" when I am trying to fetch this data. Here is my code....

Comment: Shitt, now I don't know how to post code in this comment... :(
Character limit...!! :(

Comment: `JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

try 
{
 // Getting Array of Contacts
 data = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
 JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(0);
 // Storing each json item in variable
 like = c.getString(TAG_LIKE);
 Log.i("Like Count",like);
} catch (JSONException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
LikeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLike);
LikeTv.setText(like);`